# Select ID that doesn't have field with certain content

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
userID | key      | value
1        color      green
1        eyes       blue
1        hair       brunette
2        color      red
```

How can I select all the userIDs that don't have a key 'eyes'?

Answer (score 1):

Using a single query you can just get a count for key = eyes and compare this count to be zero to have userIDs who don't have a key named as eyes

```
select `userID`,
sum(`key` = 'eyes') `count`
from t
group by `userID`
having `count` = 0
```

### [`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97d54/1)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the `LEFT JOIN` ... `IS NULL` approach:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT userID
     FROM table_name tn
LEFT JOIN table_name tn2
       ON tn2.userID = tn1.userID
      AND tn2.key = eyes
    WHERE tn2.userID IS NULL
```

This tends to outperform other approaches when tables are properly indexed.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userID
FROM table
WHERE userID NOT IN (SELECT b.userID
                     FROM table b
                     WHERE b.key = 'eyes')
```

You'd be better off to have another `Users` table from which you could select the `userId` numbers, and if you did you could just substitute that out for the first `FROM table` and remove the `DISTINCT` requirement. In fact, you could even `SELECT * FROM users` if you had that, if that was what you were going for, to get all the details about any users who didn't have the key.

But this should work, in any event.